# Windows Mobile app development using VS2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, mobile, mobile-application

I am starting to develop Windows Mobile 6 apps using Windows Mobile SDK. I do not have Visual Studio 2008. Is there a way or work around to program using windows mobile SDK in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support or work around for developing for Windows Mobile 6.x or 5.x in Visual Studio 2010 (w or wo SP1)